# Python popen python.exe

Tags: python, windows

I'm rather puzzled by why the code below doesn't print stdout and exit, instead it hangs (on windows). Any reason why?

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

def main():
    proc = Popen(
        'C:/Python33/python.exe',
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    proc.stdin.write(b'exit()\r\n')
    proc.stdin.flush()
    print(proc.stdout.read(1))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following:

```
proc.stdin.flush()
```

with:

```
proc.stdin.close()
```

Otherwise the subprocess `python.exe` will wait forever stdin to be closed.

---

Alternative: using communicate()

```
proc = Popen(...)
out, err = proc.communicate(b'exit()\r\n')
print(out)  # OR print(out[:1]) if you want only the first byte to be print.
```

Comment: Nothing is printed then, python should at least write something to stdout.

Comment: @simonzack, Because you didn't give anything except `exit()` to the interpreter.

Comment: @simonzack, Try `proc.stdin.write(b'print(123);exit()\r\n')`.